# How can I use drag-down to copy values horizontally?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am dealing with one table full of digits and I want to use drag-down function to take digits horizontally every two or three columns if there is digits in the cell. Here is part of my table:

```
   A   B   C
1  27  28  26
2  34  34   
3  38  37   
4  42  41   
5  48  47
```

I want them to be in a column like this:

```
A
27
28
26
34
34
38
37
```

It is fairly labor if I use Transpose of Paste special only， Any magic formula can help me out?

Comment: Based upon the additional info you've provided in the answers comments, you can't do this without either having blanks in the cells necessary to fill out a range (Column C, Rows 2-5) or using VBA to process through the data in an iterative basis.  How much data are you talking? Tens or Thousands of rows/columns? Also, is VBA an option for you?

Comment: Thank you David! Hundreds of rows and 4 columns! VBA is not an option for me now as I am not an advanced user of MS yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have a workaround which makes it possible in about 4 steps:

1. Copy the three (or more) columns and paste them in a new Word Document. Click on the little paste button that appears and select "Keep text only".
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to get the Find/Replace popup and put `^t@^013` in find, put `^p` in replace. Click the "More" button and check "Use Wildcards", then click "Replace All". This step is to remove extra tab characters.
3. Now do a Find on `^t@` and replace all by `^p`.
4. You will find that everything got in one column, which you can copy and paste directly in excel.

---

If you have Notepad++ (or another text editor with regex find/replace), it's just as easy:

1. Copy the three (or more) columns and paste them in a new Notepad++ file.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to get the Find/Replace popup and put `\t\r?` in find, put `\n` in replace and check the "Extended" option. Replace all.
3. You will find that everything got in one column, which you can copy and paste directly in excel.

Comment: Thanks a Ton! Word 2010 also needs ^013 as ^p doesn't work. In the poped out Paste Special window I chose "Skip blank" but still the blank cells are there. Is there any way to get rid of the blank cells?

Comment: @Juliet - I cut down on the steps so it's easier. But back to your issue, you can do a "Find `^t@^013` Replace `^p`", then "Find `^t` Replace `^p`. I will add it to my answer in a moment.

Comment: @Juliet I've updated my answer now.

Comment: Jerry, this time it works perfectly without empty cells on my 2010! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Juliet I'm happy to learn it :) You're welcome!

Comment: Perfecto! Very good and easy to do!

Answer (score 1):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is very good for this kind of manipulation.  Save the worksheet as a CSV, then open it in NP++.  Use the Find/Replace dialog (ctrl-H), and ensure that Search Mode is set to 'Extended'.

Step 1: Find/replace `,\r` with nothing (blank); that will get rid of the trailing commas, and prevent the blank lines:

[image]

Step 2: Find/replace `,` with `\n`; that will replace the commas with line breaks, putting all the values into one column which you can copy/paste back to Excel:

[image]

Comment: Geoff, I downloaded NP++ to do it and it also works perfectly. I will dig more about the usage of NP++. Thanks.

Comment: No worries - glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any "magic formula", but I know you can use the transpose feature to cut and paste a row of data into a column. You did not state what version you are using, so it may be a little different by version.

Highlight, right click and cut the row of data you want to move. Right click in the top cell you want the range of data to go to, then select the `Transpose` button on the menu (below).

[image]

Note: older versions have a `Paste Special` context menu which contains the `Transpose` option.

Comment: Excel 2010 still has the context menu.  Either select it from **Ribbon > Home > Paste > Special (via little down arrow)** or by keyboard shortcut **Alt,E,S**.

Comment: Thank you! I am using MS EXCEL 2010. I have used Transpose but the problem is, I want it jump automatically when there is no digits in the cell(because Column C sometimes has content in some rows yet not in some rows), I still have to Cut&paste after using the Transpose. As there are lots of rows, so my cut&paste work will be huge.

Comment: Those are details which would help in the initial question. Are you familiar with Macros or VBA?

Comment: You could also use Notepad++ if you have a text file of your data. It is a free powerful text editor.

Comment: I am not familiar with Macro, nor VBA. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to use basic Excel spreadsheet functionality while avoiding a huge amount of cutting and pasting. By way of example, let's assume your data is in cells `A2:D6` and you want to put the rearranged data in column F.

In cell `F2`, enter the following formula:

```
  =OFFSET($A$2,INT((ROW(F2)-ROW($F$2))/4),MOD(ROW(F2)-ROW($F$2),4))
```

and copy it down column F for 4 x the number of rows in your original data, in this case, 4 x 5, which puts the last formula in cell `F21`.

This will give you a list with zeros scattered among the list, representing the cells in the data for which there were no values.

You can get rid of the zeros by filtering column F. Put a header label in cell `F1` (any will do). With a cell in column `F` selected, chose `Sort and Filter` / `Filter` from the ribbon. Open the drop-down list on the header label and uncheck the value zero.

Select the filtered list and special paste it as values in another column, say column G.

Now remove the filter from the column F list and erase the formulas. Finally, cut and paste (or drag and drop) into column F the new list of values, sans zeros, from column G.

Comment: Chuff, this is INDEED the Drag-down function and it works perfectly! The only issue for average users is the formula in the case but I can definitely master this formula after a few times of practice. Thank you so much!